# Need help to find out the root cause of SQL Injection in PL sql package

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

We have some packages in PL SQL and we did some security scan by Veracode. We have some to solve some SQL injection problem. I am attaching the code and the line number from where it shows the error. We would like to know the root cause and proposed solution.

Below is the line showing the SQL injection issue.
dbms_sql.parse( v_cid, v_where( ASCII( p_nav)), dbms_sql.NATIVE );

```
    procedure lookup_map_ccl_table
                      (  p_id           IN VARCHAR2
                       , p_nav          IN VARCHAR2
                       , p_trace        IN PLS_INTEGER
                       , p_nl_ctry_cd   IN syn_cls_types.t_ctry_cd
                       , p_first_ccl_cd IN syn_cls_types.t_us_ccl_cd
                       , p_last_ccl_cd  IN syn_cls_types.t_us_ccl_cd
                       , p_page_size    IN PLS_INTEGER
                       , p_error_cd     IN syn_cls_errors.t_error_no
                       , p_us_ccl_cd    IN syn_cls_types.t_us_ccl_cd
                          , p_cims_ccl_cd  IN syn_cls_snf2_tmpl_cims.t_cims_us_ccl_cd
                         , p_tech_cd      IN syn_cls_snf2_tmpl_cims.t_cims_tech_cd
              , p_filter_us_ccl_cd IN syn_cls_types.t_us_ccl_cd
              , p_filter_cims_ccl_cd IN syn_cls_snf2_tmpl_cims.t_cims_us_ccl_cd               , p_filter_tech_cd IN syn_cls_snf2_tmpl_cims.t_cims_tech_cd
              , p_error_txt_passed IN VARCHAR2
-- The Parameter below is introduced for SWH SiteMinder
            , RememberMe    IN VARCHAR2                DEFAULT NULL
              )

is
   v_first_ccl_cd   syn_cls_types.t_us_ccl_cd;
   v_last_ccl_cd    syn_cls_types.t_us_ccl_cd;
   v_error_no       syn_cls_errors.t_error_no    := syn_cls_errors.ERR_OK;
   v_aktTrace       syn_cls_trace.t_trace        := syn_cls_trace.trace_init( p_Trace <> syn_cls_constants.CONST_FALSE_INT );
   v_output         syn_cls_www_template.t_outputcontents;
   v_line_output    syn_cls_www_template.t_outputcontents;
   v_cla_user       syn_cls_types.t_cla_user;
   v_cla_websession syn_cls_types.t_cla_websession;
   v_cid            PLS_INTEGER;
   v_ignore         PLS_INTEGER;

   v_base1_table    DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2_TABLE;
   v_base2_table    DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2_TABLE;
   v_base3_table    DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2_TABLE;
   v_index_1        PLS_INTEGER := 1.0;
   v_index_2        PLS_INTEGER := 1.0;
   v_index_3        PLS_INTEGER := 1.0;
   v_no_found       PLS_INTEGER := 0.0;
   v_conv_table     owa_text.multi_line := owa_text.new_multi;  -- collect table output in here
   v_order_desc     BOOLEAN := (p_nav = syn_cls_constants.CONST_NAV_PREVIOUS
                              OR p_nav = syn_cls_constants.CONST_NAV_LAST );
   v_template_nm    syn_cls_types.t_template_nm  := SYN_CLS_SNF2_TMPL_CIMS.NAME_SNF2_ADM_US_CCL_MAP_TBL;
   v_heading        syn_cls_types.t_template_dtl := owa_util.ite(p_id = 'CIMS', SYN_CLS_SNF2_TMPL_CIMS.PAGETITLE_CIMS_TO_CLASS_MAP, SYN_CLS_SNF2_TMPL_CIMS.PAGETITLE_CLASS_TO_CIMS_MAP);
   v_where          syn_cls_admin_library.t_where;
   pagesize_option_list  syn_cls_types.t_template_dtl := '';
   curr_page_size   PLS_INTEGER;
   like_comand      syn_cls_types.t_template_dtl;
   v_ccl_cd         VARCHAR2(256);

   TBL_NAME         syn_cls_types.t_template_dtl;

   SELECT_CCL_TAB        syn_cls_types.t_template_dtl;
   ORDER_CCL_TAB_ASC     syn_cls_types.t_template_dtl;
   ORDER_CCL_TAB_DESC    syn_cls_types.t_template_dtl;

   v_line_idx           PLS_INTEGER;
begin

   if p_id = 'CLASS' then
    TBL_NAME := 'CLA_US_CCL_CLASS_TO_CIMS';
   elsif p_id = 'CIMS' then
    TBL_NAME := 'CLA_US_CCL_CIMS_TO_CLASS';
   end if;

   --syn_cls_trace.trace_it( p_Trace, TRACEUS_CCL_TABLE,'test');
  SELECT_CCL_TAB := 'SELECT US_CCL_CD, CIMS_US_CCL_CD, CIMS_TECH_CD  FROM ' || TBL_NAME;
  ORDER_CCL_TAB_ASC := 'ORDER BY US_CCL_CD ASC';
  ORDER_CCL_TAB_DESC := 'ORDER BY US_CCL_CD DESC';

  curr_page_size := syn_cls_admin_library.define_default_page_size(CCL_TBL_PAGE_SIZE_OPTS,pagesize_option_list,p_page_size);

  if (p_filter_us_ccl_cd is null OR INSTR(p_filter_us_ccl_cd, FILTER_ALL) = 0) then
        like_comand := ' (( US_CCL_CD ) Like ''' || p_filter_us_ccl_cd || FILTER_ALL  || ''') AND';
  else
        like_comand := ' (( US_CCL_CD ) Like ''' || p_filter_us_ccl_cd || ''') AND';
  end if;

  if (p_filter_cims_ccl_cd is null OR INSTR(p_filter_cims_ccl_cd, FILTER_ALL) = 0) then
      like_comand := like_comand || ' (( CIMS_US_CCL_CD ) Like ''' || p_filter_cims_ccl_cd || FILTER_ALL || ''') AND';
  else
      like_comand := like_comand || ' (( CIMS_US_CCL_CD ) Like ''' || p_filter_cims_ccl_cd || ''') AND';
  end if;

  if (p_filter_tech_cd is null OR INSTR(p_filter_tech_cd, FILTER_ALL) = 0) then
      like_comand := like_comand || ' (( CIMS_TECH_CD ) Like ''' || p_filter_tech_cd || FILTER_ALL || ''') ';
  else
      like_comand := like_comand || ' (( CIMS_TECH_CD ) Like ''' || p_filter_tech_cd || ''') ';
  end if;
/*
  like_comand := ' (( US_CCL_CD ) Like ''' || p_filter_us_ccl_cd  || ''') AND' ||
                 ' (( CIMS_US_CCL_CD ) Like ''' || p_filter_cims_ccl_cd || ''') AND' ||
                 ' (( CIMS_TECH_CD ) Like ''' || p_filter_tech_cd     || ''') ';
*/
  v_where( ASCII(syn_cls_constants.CONST_NAV_FIRST) )   := SELECT_CCL_TAB || ' Where' || like_comand || ORDER_CCL_TAB_ASC;
  v_where( ASCII(syn_cls_constants.CONST_NAV_LAST ) )   := SELECT_CCL_TAB || ' Where' || like_comand || ORDER_CCL_TAB_DESC;
  v_where( ASCII(syn_cls_constants.CONST_NAV_NEXT ) )   := SELECT_CCL_TAB || ' Where' || like_comand
                            || ' And ( US_CCL_CD >= ''' || p_last_ccl_cd  || ' '') ' || ORDER_CCL_TAB_ASC;
  v_where( ASCII(syn_cls_constants.CONST_NAV_PREVIOUS)) := SELECT_CCL_TAB || ' Where' || like_comand
                            || ' And ( US_CCL_CD <= ''' || p_first_ccl_cd || ' '') ' || ORDER_CCL_TAB_DESC;

  -- check user session, issue login screen if necessary
  syn_cls_www_access.checkAndInitUserSession( v_aktTrace
                                              , v_cla_user
                                              , v_cla_websession
                                              , v_template_nm
                                              , v_heading
                                              , v_error_no
                                              --, owa_util.ite(p_id='CIMS',syn_cls_grants.GRNT_ADMEXPUS,syn_cls_grants.GRNT_ADMEXPEU)
                                              , syn_cls_grants.GRNT_ADMCIMSMAP );
                                              --, syn_cls_grants.GRNT_INLOGIN );

   if ( v_error_no <> syn_cls_errors.ERR_OK ) then
      syn_cls_www_template.getOutputFields( v_aktTrace, v_output,v_template_nm);
      syn_cls_www_access.prepare_login_template(v_akttrace, v_output, v_error_no, FALSE);
      GOTO ccl_label;
   end if;

   -- read the HTML template for Main
   syn_cls_www_template.getOutputFields(  v_aktTrace
                                        , v_line_output
                                        , v_template_nm
                                        , p_nl_ctry_cd );

   -- compose the dynamic SQL-statement, bind local variables and execute it
   v_cid := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
   dbms_sql.parse( v_cid, v_where( ASCII( p_nav)), dbms_sql.NATIVE );
```

Comment: welcome, may be try using dbms_assert before doing parse

Comment: Can you please help me to write statement for DMBS_assert?